# After upgrading to Anaconda 2020.02 "import pandas as pd" fails to be executed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda3

Error Message:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <modul> "Unable to required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed
```

I did try re-installing numpy, pandas and mkl-services to no avail. Strangely, the code executes fine in Spyder, but simply won't run via "double-click" pointing towards `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you are missing the numpy dependency. try install with conda:`pip uninstall pandas` then `conda install pandas`

Comment: I uninstalled with pip and then tried to re-install with conda. It says "all requested packages already installed" and when I run my script the error is now that there is no modul pandas. looks like the pip did work, but the conda not. should i reinstall with pip?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yo_Chris I was able to solve my problem by de-/re-installing first pandas using pip and then doing the same for numpy.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

As a note I did try those steps with conda before, but that did not solve the problem. I did think back then that conda and pip work the same. Apparently that is not the case.

Thanks again for letting me try pip!